# Show runtime for each rspec example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec, rspec-rails

currently I'm running more than 1k examples and it's taking a long time to complete (more than **20 minutes!!!**).

I'd like to identify which examples are the ones taking more time to complete, is there any way to run rspec and return the time each example takes to complete(individually)? I'm using **rspec 1.3.0** and **rspec-rails 1.2.3**

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2742-the-road-to-faster-tests

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use profiling to list your 10 slowest examples:

```
spec -p spec/*/*_spec.rb --colour --format profile
```

If you run this on a specific test suite you can get the 10 slowest examples from a smaller subset of examples:

```
spec -p spec/models/user_spec.rb --format profile
```

#### Newer Versions of Rspec

For newer versions of rspec you should use the `--profile` option:

```
rspec spec/ --profile         | (shows the 10 slowest examples)
rspec spec/ --profile 2       | (shows the 2  slowest examples)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be easy to add support for the N slowest examples!

Comment: The "profile" format is not present in the version of Rspec I'm using, 2.11.0

Comment: I think in the newer versions of RSpec you only need to use the `--profile` option.

Comment: you can have those params globally in ~/.rspec - a '--param stuff' per line

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the `rails_helper.rb` file

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.profile_examples = true
end
```

now running `rspec` gives some output like this:

```
(times of each test ^^, then)
Finished in 2 minutes 25.1 seconds (files took 1.22 seconds to load)
71 examples, 0 failures, 15 pending
```