# Rails rspecs and cucumber test show time elapse of each tests

Tags: rspec, cucumber, elapsedtime

I am quite new to ruby on rails. I can't figure it out on how to show time elapse on every tests. For now I am studying rspecs and cucumber. I ran all the test by running command rake. And when every test is executed, I want it to show a timer. I want to display the time elapsed on every specific test. Can we do it like just a global function that will listen to every test processes?

Please help me.

Comment: for *every* test? What if you have thousands of tests in your app? >_>

Comment: I want to benchmark each test and just display the 10 slowest.

Comment: then `rspec --profile` is perfect because that's what it does by default.

Comment: Ok, how about cucumber and other tests?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, my recommendation would be to use the first one, as it's already provided by Rspec.

#### 1. Use `rspec --profile`

This is a built-in feature of Rspec and will show you the times for the 10 slowest specs. Read [Show runtime for each rspec example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856500/show-runtime-for-each-rspec-example) for more details.

#### 2. Use global Before/After

You can also create your own solution, in `spec/spec_helper` (or wherever you configure Rspec), add something like:

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
 config.before(:each) do
   @start_timer = Time.now
 end

  config.after(:each) {}
    puts "Spec ran in #{Time.now - @start_timer}s"
  end
end
```